# Manipulate y-axis scale using ggforce facet_zoom

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggforce

I am plotting a time series and I want to zoom on few observations. This can be done using `facet_zoom()` from `ggforce` package.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)
library(stringr)


airquality %>% 
  mutate(month_day = seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), 
                         by = "month", 
                         length.out = n())) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = month_day, y = Temp)) + 
  geom_line() +
  facet_zoom(x = month_day > "2010/1/1" & month_day < "2010/9/1")
```

Resulting plot:

[image]

However, I would like to manipulate the scale on y-axis of the lower panel plot, making it smaller. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `xy` instead of `x`, and set `horizontal` to `TRUE` to auto fit the y-axis:

```
airquality %>% 
  mutate(month_day = seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), 
                         by = "month", 
                         length.out = n())) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = month_day, y = Temp)) + 
  geom_line() +
  facet_zoom(xy = month_day > "2010/1/1" & month_day < "2010/9/1", horizontal = FALSE)
```

[image]